# How to resolve "Incorrect table definition" on Magento?

Tags: magento2, database

I want to restore my Magento database back up, but I get below error message:

```
ERROR 1293 (HY000) at line 68: Incorrect table definition; 
there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you have any direct modifications in the database?

Comment: NO @Mohit Kumar Arora

Comment: Can you please show line 68? because there is an issue with date field datatype.